# Set Site Icon programmatically (eg. using `wp cli`)

Tags: wp-cli, icon, favicon

Wordpress has a ["Site Icon"](https://en.support.wordpress.com/site-icons/) feature that serves correctly-sized favicons and so on to browsers. Is there a way to drive this feature programmatically, eg. by uploading media and setting an option with `wp cli`?

Comment: Why not just put the favicon.ico in the site's root? It will not take effect immediately (due to browser caching), but it will work.

Comment: > Why not just put the favicon.ico in the site's root?

1. I'd like to use the Wordpress functionality for serving different size to different clients
2. It's a hack since it's not how Wordpress customization/theming is supposed to work (eg. I want to place stuff like this in my theme or media directory, for example)

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: I can see your question was not answered.  Were you able to solve this on your own?

Answer (score 2):

Use wp-cli commands `wp media import` and `wp option update`.

`wp media import <file>` : Creates attachments from local files or URLs.

`wp option update <key>` : Updates an option value.

**Image from theme folder** :

```
$ wp media import "$(wp theme path)/theme/assets/images/logo.png" --porcelain | wp option update site_icon
```

**Image from url** :

```
$ wp media import "https://source.unsplash.com/random/512x512" --porcelain | wp option update site_icon
```

The flag [--porcelain] output just the new attachment ID.

**References** :

https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/media/import/

https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/option/update/

Comment: Can you elaborate further on your answer so it can be understood better? E.g. I see you're piping values and using `--porcelain`? What if the file isn't a part of the theme? Use the `edit` functionality to expand on your answer

Answer (score 2):

Site logo/icons are set through option named 'site_icon'. You can update the site icon through wp-cli by running `wp option update site_icon 4444` replacing 4444 with the post_id of the image that you want to use.

BUT: when you upload an image through the customizer,  additional image sizes (as of this writing, defined in src/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-site-icon.php);
besides what you are already have registered; are created.

You'll have to manually create those images if you update the option through wp-cli.

Answer (score 0):

The 'official rules' about site icons are here:https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#link-type-icon .

They provide this example of site icons for several sizes:

```
<link rel=icon href=favicon.png sizes="16x16" type="image/png">
  <link rel=icon href=windows.ico sizes="32x32 48x48" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon">
  <link rel=icon href=mac.icns sizes="128x128 512x512 8192x8192 32768x32768">
  <link rel=icon href=iphone.png sizes="57x57" type="image/png">
  <link rel=icon href=gnome.svg sizes="any" type="image/svg+xml">
```

The above link also specifies if the 'link rel=icon ...' is not specified, then the /favicon.ico file (in the site root) will be used.

It further states:

> "If multiple icons are provided, the user agent must select the most
>   appropriate icon according to the type, media, and sizes attributes."

("User agent" is the browser rendering the site.)

Also, see one of the answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943771/adding-a-favicon-to-a-static-html-page that references an application to create all of the different icon sizes and the code needed to use them:

> Actually, to make your favicon work in all browsers, you must have
>   more than 10 images in the correct sizes and formats.
>
> I created an App ([faviconit.com](http://faviconit.com/)) so people don´t have to create all
>   these images and the correct tags by hand.

I have not tried the application referenced. YMMV.

And, this question/answer might also be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53464667/best-practice-for-ordering-icon-link-tags-in-html-head .

Answer (score 0):

I managed to set the favicon of my wordpress using Wordpress CLI:

```
FAVICON_TITLE="mysite-favicon"
FAVICON_PATH="~/dev/favicon.png"
wp media import ${FAVICON_PATH} --title=${FAVICON_TITLE}
FAVICON_ID=$(wp post list --post_type=attachment --post_title=${FAVICON_TITLE} --format=ids)
wp option update site_icon ${FAVICON_ID}
```